# T-SQL: Filter by Category including Subs

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following tables in my database:

```
Categories:
- Id (PK)
- ParentId (FK to Categories.Id)
- Name

Products:
- Id (PK)
- CategoryId (FK to Categories.Id)
- Name
```

I'd like to write a query to get all products within a category (given a category id) including it's sub categories and their subs and so on. Please note that I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I'm sure many people have had this problem before but I can't think of what to search for to solve. Appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: How about creating a view with all concerned tables with joins which gives un-normalized data at low-level sub table. And then use distinct/group by to retrieve required entity from the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do Recursive-like queries using [Common Table Expressions](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml).

```
WITH CategoryHierarchy (CategoryId, ParentId) AS
(
  SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Categories
  -- This is the categoryId:
  WHERE Id = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT c.Id as CategoryId, c.ParentId
  FROM Categories c
  INNER JOIN CategoryHierarchy cr ON cr.CategoryId = c.ParentId

)
SELECT * FROM Products p
WHERE p.CategoryId IN (SELECT c.CategoryID FROM CategoryHierarchy c)
```

SqlFiddle for that solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0910/1